# Crawling specific elements of table, using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i have the below abstract html code and i want to extract part of table data:

```
<table class="datatable datatable--test datatable--tester ">
            <tbody><tr class="datatable__rowth">
            <tr class="datatable__rowtd datatable__rowtd--fakeheader">
                    <tr class="datatable__rowtd">
                    <tr class="datatable__rowtd">
                    <tr class="datatable__rowtd">
                    <tr class="datatable__rowtd">
            <tr class="datatable__rowtd datatable__rowtd--fakeheader">
                    <tr class="datatable__rowtd">
                    <tr class="datatable__rowtd">
                     
                    </tbody></table>
```

More specifically, i want to extract `<tr class="datatable__rowtd">` of first `<tr class="datatable__rowtd datatable__rowtd--fakeheader">`, but i don't know how?

I have tried the below command:

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='datatable datatable--test datatable--tester ']/tr[@class='datatable__rowtd']")
```

but this returns as expected 6 `<tr class="datatable__rowtd">`, while i want the first 4.

Also, i tried the below command, which doen't work:

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='datatable datatable-test datatable--tester ']//tr[@class='datatable__rowtd datatable__rowtd--fakeheader'][0]//tr[@class='datatable__rowtd']")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

To identify the first `<tr>` with *class* value as *`datatable__rowtd`* you can use:

```
row = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='datatable datatable--test datatable--tester ']/tbody/tr[@class='datatable__rowtd']")
```

---

To identify the first two `<tr>`s with *class* value as *`datatable__rowtd`* you can [***slice***](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/list-slicing) the *list* as follows:

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='datatable datatable--test datatable--tester ']/tbody//tr[@class='datatable__rowtd']")[:2]
```

Comment: What happens when i have more tr[@class='datatable__rowtd']? I want to read the rows of 1st tr[@class='datatable__rowtd datatable__rowtd--fakeheader'] only. Sometimes they are 2 and sometimes more. I modified my example.

Comment: @terminxd Instead of **2** if you want **4**, you just need to replace `[:2]` with `[:4]`

Comment: but the size of rows is variable. Sometimes, i have 2, sometimes 10 etc. Generally, i want to crawl the row, which are under 1st //tr[@class='datatable__rowtd datatable__rowtd--fakeheader']